# Meaning of $ and # symbols for normal and root user in terminal

Tags: command-line, prompt

What do the symbols mean `#` and `$`. Why `#` for root?

Where do these conventions come from?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen the answer doesn't address where doss the convention come from.

Comment: Tradition; It was that way when I learnt it early 80s when we were told it was a convention & they had no special meaning other than $=work (money; where you earn your living), #=danger (it could go bad and you'll see the # as appeared then on batman tv shows instead of violence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tradition; It was that way when I learnt it early 80s when we were told it was a convention & they had no special meaning other than $=work (*money; where you will earn your living*), #=danger (it could go bad and you'll see the "#"'s as appeared then on batman tv shows instead of hits or violence)

The problem is they can easily be changed, and are shell specific.  I learnt what I said before at univeristy where we used bourne SHell; the modern BASH having replaced original bourne SHell so it follows its traditions.

If you use other shells those "$" and "#" could be replaced by other characters (*eg. "%" depending on shell chosen*).

Further as stated they can be replaced via $PS1 (prompt) so should **not** be relied on to mean anything anyway.

They are at best an indication of what shell you **may** be using, and what level of environment (user or root) you **may** be in - but it's far safer to assume nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had trouble googling that question for some reason.

Comment: The correct answer is that `#` is the comment character.  All the dangerous commands that you're typing as root look like they are commented out if you plonk them into a shell script, or accidentally copy them and paste them back into the terminal. If you quote your session in an e-mail, like to give someone some admin commands, they can't just blindly paste the whole swath of them into their shell.

Comment: In the bash `PS1` prompt syntax, there is a `\$` code which produces `#` and `$` depending on the privileges of the user. I don't think these can be customized; the only way would be to plonk a literal character there instead of `\$`.

Comment: I don't like my chances of finding my university lecturer & setting him straight, nor the students I probably repeated it to in tutorial (as a tutor) - though copy/paste wasn't very common on dumb terminal/tapes/cards still then in use in that era (unlike today so I suspect that's a more modern reason).  We didn't have mice, and `vi` was great as most terms still didn't have arrow keys.